# jQuery after ajax call, events with the same Ids stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Not sure if this is a bug or I am not suppose be doing this.

I have a page with sidebars that loads the main body dynamically.

For page1, I have a callback for an element `#id1`, which works on initial load.

After the user navigates to page2, the main content will get replaced by contents of page2, which also has an element with `#id1`, they serve the same purpose. events are initialized there as well.

The problem is that everything on page 2 would work except the event associated with `#id1`.

If navigating back to page 1, `#id1` wouldn't work as well.

After looking at the console, I found that when calling `$("#id1")` sometimes give me the initial load element (not destroyed?), which is probably the reason.

The ajax load simply uses:

```
$.get(path, function(data) {$('#main').html(data)});
```

Any idea what's going on here?

If the old elements are not 'properly destroyed in jquery', what is suppose to be done here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it's not clear exactly what you're binding, the solution is to use (depending on your jQuery version) `live()` or `on()` to ensure that you bind to elements that aren't in the DOM at execution time.

jQuery 1.7+: `on()`

```
$(document).on('click', '.selector', function() { ... });
```

jQuery <1.7: `live()`

```
$('.selector').live('click', function() { ... });
```

Comment: Awesome! Thx man!! I have always taught it wouldn't make any diffrence if you bind with `.bind` or with `.on`

Comment: Using `.bind` binds directly to the element(s) specified by the selector. If you add new elements later that would match the selector, they will have no event bound to them. Using `.live` / `.on` will ensure that even newly-created elements will respond to your bound events, although this makes them slower so you should only use them when needed.

Answer (score 1):

**Remember that an ID should only occur once**

Because you don't know what elements with `ID`'s may still be living in the DOM after the Ajax call you should stick with `classname`'s instead.

With that you can use jQuery's `.live()` to bind to elements that have been dynamically loaded.

Comment: Um, the problem is that the Id does only occurs once, but if you reload the page using ajax, the bindings are different now and it doesn't make sense to change the id every time the page is loaded. T__T

Answer (score 1):

You have to generate dynamic id for that. When you click the right bar option the id will generated and place the id in the body element "id" tag.So you know that which id is generated for which page. Call a javascript function on "onclick" event and pass that id to this function then call the body element as `$("#id"+that generated_id).something;`
I think this will help.